# How to scrape data from XML where Child roots don't exist using Python?

Tags: python, xml, pandas, xpath, web-scraping

There are 3 objects with different number of attributes for each object. How to scrape each of their properties in a dataframe?

```
<movie>'ABC'</movie>
<meta name="actor" content="Joseph"></meta>
<meta name="actor_ATTR" content="Male"></meta>
<meta name="actor_ATTR" content="32 Yrs"></meta>

<meta name="actor" content="Alex"></meta>
<meta name="actor_ATTR" content="Male"></meta>

<meta name="actor" content="John"></meta>
<meta name="actor_ATTR" content="Male"></meta>
<meta name="actor_ATTR" content="32 Yrs"></meta>
<meta name="actor_ATTR" content="3 awards"></meta>
```

and so on

Required output dataframe:

Name     Attributes

Joseph   [Male, 32 Yrs]

Alex    [Male]

John    [Male, 32 Yrs, 3 awards]

Comment: We need more information. Is the xml a file that you are reading or is it a BeautifulSoup object that you are reading from the web?

Comment: It's also important to include one complete record of one movie; for example the opening and closing tags that separate it from the next movie.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty complex operation, so I'll try to explain as we go along, but it's not going to be easy to digest:

```
from lxml import etree
import elementpath //the core element here is the xpath method intersect(); it's an xpath 2.0 function, so lxml (which only supports xpath 1.0, doesn't work here, so we need this library which supports xpath 2.0
import pandas as pd

movie = """[your xml above]"""
root = etree.XML(movie)

columns = ['Name','Sex','Age','Awards'] #prepare the dataframe columns
rows = [] #initialize the collection of information about actors
anchor = '@name="actor"' #this isn't strictly necessary, but because the xpath expressions get progressively convoluted, I believe this will make it more readable
actor_count = elementpath.select(root,f'count(//meta[{anchor}])') # how many actors are there? Note that this is the first, but not last, use of f-strings; you should read up on those as well
meta_count = elementpath.select(root,'count(//meta)') #how many items are there?

for c in range(actor_count): #for each actor
    row = [] #initialize a list containing data about this actor
    #the intersect() method start at top and looks down, than goes to the bottom and looks up, then selects what's in the middle; this is where it gets really complex, so you'll just have to read up on it
    top_down = f'//meta[{anchor}][{c+1}]/(self::meta,following-sibling::meta)' #note the use of {c+1} instead of just {c}; that's because the range() function is python, which counts from zero, while xpath counts from 1, so you need to account for that

    bottom_up = f'(//meta[{anchor}][preceding-sibling::meta[1][not({anchor})]]\
    ,//meta[count(./preceding-sibling::*) = {meta_count}])[{c+1}]/(self::meta[not({anchor})],\
    preceding-sibling::meta)'    

    src_exp = f'{top_down} intersect {bottom_up}'
    entries = elementpath.select(root,src_exp) 
    #if everything works, this should have separated the actors' data into separate groups
    for entry in entries:
        row.append(entry.attrib['content']) #add this actor's data to the actor's row

    if len(entries)<4:
        row += ['NA'] * (4 - len(entries)) #since some actors don't have all data items, the row for such an actor needs to be padded with 'NA's.
    rows.append(row) #add this actor's data to the general data pool
pd.DataFrame(rows,columns=columns) #load the whole thing into a dataframe
```

Output:

```
    Name    Sex     Age     Awards
0   Joseph  Male    32 Yrs  NA
1   Alex    Male    NA      NA
2   John    Male    32 Yrs  3 awards
```